# Flask does not show up icon

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, favicon

[see line 16. I implied correct file path to add favicon.ico.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4S2V.png)

[But when I run the flask icon does not show up. What is the problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAvFc.jpg)

Comment: Images of text are not searchable, they are not accessible, and they are less useful than the text to people who are trying to help answer the question because they can not be copied and edited into an answer. Either replace the images of text with the text they contain, or augment the images with the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<link href="../static/assets/images/favicon.ico" rel="icon">
```

Comment: My browser used cache. Pressing ctrl+F5 solves the problem.